# Visual Studio Code Api: Get active signature

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I develop language-extension with SignatureHelpProvider.
Some functions have several signatures, so I push several SignatureInfo to `SignatureHelp.signatures` array.

The problem is - how to get current active signature selected by user?
Current realization switches the `activeSingature` to `0` every time User types a character.

Also in vscode >=1.6 you must set an `activeSingature` to some value - otherwise the hint mini-window won't pop up.

Any ideas how to get this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to decide which signature you want to set to active for your user.

It might for example be the one with fewer parameters that satisfies your activeParameter. It's your call as an extension developer.

When he types a character, you are probably invoking the signatureHelpProvider (with your trigger characters) and that's reseting activeSignature back to 0.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! The problem is that I need to guess current selected signature. But user can just type 1 symbol (or even not type) of some method or class constructor and change signature by mouse click.

Comment: @NikitaGryzlov Oh I think I understood your problem better now. I just tried this with typescript (vscode natively supports it) and they seem to have the same "bug".